# Spark task duration difference

Tags: apache-spark, scheduled-tasks, apache-spark-sql

I'm running application that loads data (.csv) from s3 into DataFrames, and than register those Dataframes as temp tables. After that, I use SparkSQL to join those tables and finally write result into db. Issue that is currently bottleneck for me is that I feel tasks are not evenly split and i get no benefits or parallelization and multiple nodes inside cluster. More precisely, this is distribution of task duration in problematic stage
[task duration distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6hmJ.png)
Is there way for me to enforce more balanced distribution ? Maybe manually writing map/reduce functions ? 
Unfortunately, this stage has 6 more tasks that are still running (1.7 hours atm), which will prove even greater deviation.

Answer (score 2):

There are two likely possibilities: one is under your control and .. *unfortunately* one is likely *not* ..

- **Skewed data**. Check that the partitions are of relatively similar size - say within a factor of three or four.
- **Inherent variability of Spark tasks runtime**.  I have seen behavior of large delays in stragglers on Spark Standalone, Yarn, and Mesos without an apparent reason.  The symptoms are:

  - extended periods (minutes) where little or no cpu or disk activity were occurring on the nodes hosting the straggler tasks
  - no apparent correlation of data size to the stragglers
  - different nodes/workers may experience the delays on subsequent runs of the same job

One thing to check:  do `hdfs dfsadmin -report` and `hdfs fsck` to see if hdfs were healthy.

Comment: I have checked hdfs, it's ok. Regarding partitioning, I think that might be issue. At first I wasn't partitioning anything, so I created 200 tasks by default. I tried to force my own partitions by `sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.a_id")..coalesce(500).toDF(); `, but there are still only 200 partitions, which you can see here: http://pokit.org/get/img/107c51b026c841ce8736150c5c663b0b.png. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I think `coalesce` will leave alone if `newPartitions >= oldPartitions`.  Try `repartition(500)` .

Comment: I've put `repartition(5000)`, and I've recognized stages with 5k tasks. However, this didn't helped in global, as again parallelization hit "the wall", and still few tasks went completely off balance. More interestingly, this was in stages with 200 tasks, so I believe there is not much I could do.  Thanks for help, I will look into alternative solutions to problem. Of course, if you have any ideas I would appreciate them.