# Spark: one task never returns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running a Spark process where all the tasks have finished successfully apart from one that is running alone for hours by now. Using `htop` I can see that the cpu is spinning but I have like the impression that it is not doing anything.

How can I make this process to finish or at least discovering what the task is doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899448/spark-task-duration-difference/37901039#37901039

Comment: You should take the PID you can see from top and run "jstack" on that PID to get a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In short: this happens fairly frequently in Spark. Take a look at [Spark task duration difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899448/spark-task-duration-difference/37901039#37901039) for possible scenarios involving: data skew, hdfs issues, and well.. it just seems to happen.

**Update for response to the OP**

`reliable` in terms of : will the job provide the right answer *at some point* - that one spark is pretty solid for.

`reliable`  In the sense of an SLA for the processing interval - which is a concern.  The skew in processing has been observed across a number of clusters running on standalone, yarn, and even mesos schedulers.   Sorry I do not have any better news.

Comment: hdfs returned as healthy. data skew looks not an issue. I have even coalesced and ripartitioned with different combinations. I just started to wondering if Spark is reliable at this point.

Comment: your first definition of "reliable" means that if I let it run soon or late it will return something?

Comment: @Randomize  That has been my experience - yes.  Here is a suggestion. Run the algo on a VERY small dataset.  You can find out if there something inherent in your closures that cause hanging.  If that works then ramp up gradually.